# Update from learn_runner.run to tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate on GCMLE

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to make sure I cover everything when updating to `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate()` instead of `learn_runner.run()`.

I am looking to base things of this GCMLE custom estimator sample which used to be:

```
learn_runner.run(
      generate_experiment_fn(
          min_eval_frequency=args.min_eval_frequency,
          eval_delay_secs=args.eval_delay_secs,
          train_steps=args.train_steps,
          eval_steps=args.eval_steps,
          export_strategies=[saved_model_export_utils.make_export_strategy(
              model.SERVING_FUNCTIONS[args.export_format],
              exports_to_keep=1
          )]
      ),
      run_config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(model_dir=args.job_dir),
      hparams=hparam.HParams(**args.__dict__)
  )
```

**export_strategies**:

Previously, the `export_strategies` would place the final model binaries in the `$job_dir/export/Servo/$timestamp`. However, when trying to convert to use tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate I cannot see how to replicate this behavior.

Following this newer custom estimator example, I have passed

```
exporter = tf.estimator.FinalExporter('saved-model', SERVING_FUNCTIONS[hparams.export_format])
```

into the EvalSpec `exporters = [exporter]` but it doesn't work as the final export strategy like previously.

**run_config**

Previously run_config was passed as an additional command with learn_runner.run(). Now my approach within my `run_experiment()` function is to pass the run_config() directly to `tf.estimator.Estimator`'s `config` parameter. Is there any functionality that I am missing with this?

Example:

```
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=hparams.job_dir,
    save_checkpoints_steps=hparams.save_checkpoint_steps,
    save_summary_steps = hparams.save_summary_steps)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn,
                                   model_dir=hparams.job_dir,
                                   config = run_config,
                                   params = hparams)
```

Is there anything with the new run_config implementation that I am missing out on from the old implementation?

Comment: Update: I noticed on my local training run that I had exports written to `INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: output/export/saved-model/temp-1518649176/saved_model.pb
DEBUG:tensorflow:Calling exporter with the `is_the_final_export=True`. which suggests that the export is exporting locally, but I'm not finding any `export` folder in the GCS location

Comment: It looks like your model_dir might not being set correctly. Are you setting --job-dir when you launch your job? Are you using argparser to parse --job-dir? Are you sending the parsed args as hparams?

Comment: @rhaertel80 thanks for the help! I am setting `--job-dir` when I launch my job and storing all parsed args in the hparams. The `job-dir` folder in GCS does have all of the checkpoints, but it just doesn't have the final `export` folder that was there previously and exists locally. I have tried passing the job-dir as both the `run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=hparams.job_dir)` and also as `tf.estimator.Estimator(model_dir=hparams.job_dir)`.  Do you need to explicitly set `export_strategies` like with `learn_runner`?

Comment: @rhaertel80 it's possible that the export is working properly, but I just can't find the model binary that I use for the `--origin` flag of `gcloud ml-engine versions create` -- previously I would set `--origin` to `MODEL_BINARIES=$GCS_JOB_DIR/export/Servo/<timestamp>` but it just doesn't exist and I can't find the `saved_model.pb` or `assets` folder or `variables` folder anywhere. I do find a folder with the `name` specified in the `FinalExporter` but it is prefixed by `eval_` and only contains a single file starting with `events.out.tfevents.`

Comment: does your job finish running or does it just hang?

Comment: @rhaertel80 The job finishes GCMLE gives a green check mark and the log shows statements like `Job completed successfully.` and `Training has already ended. But the last eval is skipped due to eval throttle_secs. Now evaluating the final checkpoint.` When I run it locally I have additional messages at completion such as `INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to: output/export/saved-model/temp-1518649176/saved_model.pb ` but nothing like this shows up in the GCMLE experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was coming from stopping condition of `num_epochs` vs `num_steps` -- it appears that tf.estimator.Estimator does not play well with `num_epochs` so you should have your stopping condition be `num_steps` if you want an export folder.

Separately, it's worth noting that if you specify both `model_dir` within `tf.estimator.Estimator()` directly and also specifying `model_dir` within `run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig()` then these names must match. The TF documentation suggests that it should be okay to specify the model_dir in both places if they are equal "model_dir: Directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. This can also be used to load checkpoints from the directory into a estimator to continue training a previously saved model. If None, the model_dir in config will be used if set. If both are set, they must be same. If both are None, a temporary directory will be used."